# ASP.NET MVC3: Cant find/access file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

```
 String DocLocation = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Files/test.pdf";
        // or
 String DocLocation = Url.Content("~/Files/test.pdf");

 var document = new FileStream(DocLocation, FileMode.Open);
 var mimeType = "application/pdf";
 var fileDownloadName = "download.pdf";

 return File(document, mimeType, fileDownloadName);
```

The first method is UnauthorizedAccessException.

The second method cant find the file.

I am trying to send a file for download. Using full desktop path seems to work.

Also, how would I display PDF in the browser instead (note, still need download option as not all are pdf)?

Comment: does your web server have access to that file?

Comment: Unlike my deployed server, there is no IIS User to set permission for. Unless Im missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Server.MapPath("~/Files/test.pdf")

Comment: This is the same result location string as my first method. Unauthorised access exception.

Comment: I would check file access on the file

Comment: Turns out the file had a readonly attribute set. They are being copied off a central file server. I didnt expect this flag to be set, though it makes sense. Thanks for the better Absolute path code.

Answer (score 2):

`File()` takes a physical path on disk.
Therefore, you can't use `Url.Content`, since that returns a relative URL for the browser.

Instead, you need `Server.MapPath`, which converts an application relative path into a full path on the local disk.

Comment: Okay. This is the same result location string as my first method. Unauthorised access exception.